# Can I have specialized template like here?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I want to have general class Vector of any dimensions with template type

```
template <typename T, unsigned D>
class Vector {
public:
    // constructors, methods and so on

protected:
    T data[D];
};
```

and specializations for 2, 3 and 4 dimensions

```
template <typename T, unsigned D>
class Vector<T, 3> {
public:
    T getX() const { return data[0]; }
    // ... 
};
```

this code, of course, doesn't work. How should I do it? If it is possible. Or, in any cases, I should use inheritance?

```
template <typename T>
class Vector3 : public Vector<T, 3> {
public:
    T getX() const { return data[0]; }
};
```

Comment: The existing answers are good, but note also that a specialization is an entirely separate class from the primary template.  In particular `Vector<T, 3>` will not have any of the members of `Vector<T,D>` such as `data` unless you declare them all over again in your specialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*gcc* prints pretty straightforward error for your code:

> error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization: D

In order to set a partial specialization you should remove parameter *D*:

```
template <typename T> // <=== No *unsigned D* here
class Vector<T, 3> {
    public:
        // implementation here
};
```

and then implement the specialization.

Comment: I thought that would make Vector<T> always has 3 dimensions, but this works correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can partially specialise your template class in any way. The only syntactic error you made is, that you should list the template parameters which are actually parameters (and not constants).

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, unsigned D>
class Vector {
public:
    // constructors, methods and so on
protected:
    T data[D];
};

template <typename T>
class Vector<T, 3> {
public:
    // the same constructors (or not?)
    T getX() const { return data[0]; }
    T data[3];
};

int main() {
    Vector<int, 3> arr;
    arr.data[0]=42;
    std::cout << arr.getX();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the specialization `Vector<T,3>` no longer lists `D`.

You can do whatever you want within the specialization. It can have a completely different body.